# Windows registry: changing showed program icon (taskbar and top left corner)

Tags: windows, windows-registry, taskbar, icons, regedit

I'm making a script to open .sh files with bash.exe and wsl.exe.
the keys I'm editing are [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\wsl.exe] and [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\bash.exe];

I wanted to change the icon the program shows when opened (both in the taskbar and in the top left corner of the application); DefaultIcon only changes the icon of the associated files, while TaskbarGroupIcon doesn't seem to do anything

Comment: If you run Ubuntu.exe or OpenSUSE.exe, the command prompt window and taskbar show the distro icon.

Comment: @Biswa i know, but that was not my intention, my script adds file association (and file drag-over) to .sh scripts, and needs bash.exe and wsl.exe, as they are present for all WSL users